# How can I create a script that loads a model and predicts only?

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to predict tomorrow's mid day temperature. From Google I have scraped together a LSTM model as it seems to be more accurate. The point here is not the value it's predicting, but being able to reuse a model and make future predictions as I want training as one service and prediction as another.

Here is the code for training a model:

```
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 20,10

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))

sql_conn = pyodbc.connect(connStr) 

query = 'SELECT Date, Temp FROM temps ORDER BY [Date] ASC'

df = pd.read_sql(query, sql_conn)

print(df.head(3))

totalRows = df["Date"].count()
trainRows = int(totalRows * 0.70)

#creating dataframe
data = df.sort_index(ascending=True, axis=0)

new_data = pd.DataFrame(index=range(0,len(df)),columns=['Date', 'Temp'])

for i in range(0,len(data)):
    new_data['Date'][i] = data['Date'][i]
    new_data['Temp'][i] = data['Temp'][i]

#setting index
new_data.index = new_data.Date
new_data.drop('Date', axis=1, inplace=True)

#creating train and test sets
dataset = new_data.values

train = dataset[0:trainRows,:]
valid = dataset[trainRows:,:]

#converting dataset into x_train and y_train
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))

scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)

x_train, y_train = [], []
for i in range(60,len(train)):
    x_train.append(scaled_data[i-60:i,0])
    y_train.append(scaled_data[i,0])

x_train, y_train = np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train)

x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0],x_train.shape[1],1))

# create and fit the LSTM network
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1],1)))
model.add(LSTM(units=50))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=1, verbose=2)

# serialize model to JSON
model_json = model.to_json()

with open("temp.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)

# serialize weights to HDF5
model.save_weights("temp.h5")

print("Saved model to disk")

#predicting 246 values, using past 60 from the train data
inputs = new_data[len(new_data) - len(valid) - 60:].values
inputs = inputs.reshape(-1,1)
inputs  = scaler.transform(inputs)

X_test = []

for i in range(60,inputs.shape[0]):
    X_test.append(inputs[i-60:i,0])

X_test = np.array(X_test)
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0],X_test.shape[1],1))

temp = model.predict(X_test)
temp = scaler.inverse_transform(temp)

rms = np.sqrt(np.mean(np.power((valid-temp),2)))

print("RMS = " + str(rms))

train = new_data[:trainRows]
valid = new_data[trainRows:]
valid['Predictions'] = temp
plt.plot(train['Temp'])
plt.plot(valid[['Temp','Predictions']])
plt.savefig('temp.png')
```

This produces the model files needed and a nice png file to quickly see how the training went.

The prediction part should be fairly simple: load last 60 data points, load model, make prediction. But how do I transform the loaded panda to model.predict?

```
sql_conn = pyodbc.connect(connStr) 

query = 'SELECT TOP(60) Date, Temp FROM Temps ORDER BY [Date] DESC'

df = pd.read_sql(query, sql_conn)

json_file = open("temp.json", "r")
loaded_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
model = model_from_json(loaded_json)

model.load_weights("temp.h5")

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

# how do I get to temp = model.predict(?)
```

If I try to simply throw the Temp values in a array and run predict i get an array:

```
x = []
for d in df['Temp']:
    x.append(d)

prediction = model.predict(x)
```

Error: **expected lstm_3_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (60, 1)**

I have to transform my values?

Comment: What prevents you from executing `model.predict` after loading the model? (There is no need to compile the model here, but it won't hurt either.) Why do you both load data from a database and from a JSON file?

Comment: Hei @IonicSolutions see my edit. I guess I just simply cant push Temp values in the predict.